# Identifier expected in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PageProcessingDemo
{
    public partial class  : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

i haven't done anything yet ,but it still showing " Identifier expected  ",and pointing to  ":" when double clicked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't specified class name.
Change your code to something like this:

```
public partial class MyPageClass : System.Web.UI.Page
```

***P.S:*** Also, you have said that:

> i haven't done anything yet

I am pretty sure that somebody has removed name of the class.

**Additional details:**
Try to add new `WebForm` to the project. Set the name of form to `WebForm1`.After clicking OK, `VisualStudio` will create three or two files depending on the type of the project:

- WebForm1.aspx
- WebForm1.aspx.cs
- WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs *(WebApplication project)*

The `*.aspx` files are the ***markup*** and the `*.aspx.cs` files are the ***code-behind files***. Code-behind files handle the .NET code for any server-side controls in the `*.aspx` files. And Asp.Net will generate your code behind files as partial classes like that:

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
```